The last letter in the TextView is cut off

I have a TextView containing Arabic letters, the text is long. At the end of each line, the text gets cut off.
How to overcome this?
This is my XML
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:clipChildren="false"
                    android:clipToPadding="false">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ayats"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:includeFontPadding="false"
                        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="17dp"
                        android:padding="14dp"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:clipChildren="false"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="#D3D3D3"
                        android:clipToPadding="false"/>
                </LinearLayout>

I have tried adding attributes
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"

How to overcome this?

is this whole text is in single textView or each line has a seperate textView

The textview is single, containing long text in Arabic
